# SQL Server - Contain Multiples Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need retrieve a value of columm with SELECT. But, I have multiple values ... 
I don't know what the user go select in checkbox...

Ex:

```
Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a1')
```

I want the result = Angulo 1

```
Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a2';'a3')
```

I want the result = Angulo 2

```
Insert into MyTable (dados) Values ('a3'; a1)
```

I want the result = Angulo 3; Angulo 1

```
Insert into MyTable (dados) Values ('a6'; 'a7'; 'a4')
```

I want the result = Angulo 6; Angulo 7;Angulo4

I am Trying with SELECT CASE WHEN. But it still fails...

Comment: Can we see your database structure? Also, what SELECT query have you tried?

Comment: @Pedro . . . Your question does not make sense.  The SQL insert statements have syntax errors (semicolons instead of commas and one column for multiple columns).  Also, `insert` does not return results, so saying "I want the result . . ." after an insert is very unclear.  Can you better describe what you need?

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
 insert into MyTable(dados)
    Values ('a6', 'a7', 'a4')
```

You are saying "I have one column to put data into called dados."  Then, you are providing three values.  This will fail in any database (even apart from the fact that the semicolons should be commas).

Perhaps you want:

```
insert into MyTable(dados)
    Values ('a6;a7;a4')
```

That is only one value, a string.

This suggests a denormalized database.  You might want three different rows in a table, one for each value, connected together by some key.

Comment: I can not. I have over 100 values ​​that can be selected in my checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are asking how to use the `IN` keyword in your `SELECT` statements?  It is a little unclear what you are trying to do.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE dados IN ('a6','a7','a4')
```

Assuming you have a table named MyTable and a column named dados with 3 rows in that table for a6, a7 and a4, this will return all the matches (in this case, all three rows).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

here are some examples if you're using sql server 2008 and above:

if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dados') is not null)
DROP TABLE #dados

select top 100 * INTO #dados FROM 
(
values(1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9)
) t(a,b,c)

select * FROM #dados

INSERT INTO #dados (a,b,c)
values(11,22,33),
    (44,55,66),
    (77,88,99)

SELECT * FROM #dados

INSERT INTO #dados (a,b,c)
SELECT * FROM 
(
values(111,222,333),
    (444,555,666),
    (777,888,999)
) t(a,b,c)

SELECT * FROM #dados

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple rows (not columns) the syntax is

```
Insert Into 
MyTable (dados) 
Values 
('a1'), 
('a2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to ask for two things.

How to insert multiple values would be done in the following way:

```
Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a6'),('a7'),('a4')
```

If you want to return the actual values 'Angulo' + the number, you can use the following:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    Dados varchar(255)
)   

Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a12') 
Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a2'),('a3')
Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a3'),('a1') 
Insert Into MyTable (dados) Values ('a6'),('a7'),('a4') 

SELECT 'Angulo'+ SUBSTRING(dados,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',dados),LEN(dados))
FROM MyTable
```

It will find the first number (assuming it's always the first number you're after) and get the rest of them. It will then append it with the prefix 'Angulo' (e.g Angulo1, Angulo7, etc)

If these aren't what you're after. Please can you explain further what you need.